# Display alertDialog onPostExecute of AsyncTask Android

Tags: java, android

I have an `asyncTask` and I want to show an `alertDialog` when the `onPostExecute` method is fired.
I declared a Context variable and I initialized it inside the `OnCreate` method like:

```
mContext = this;
```

Then in order to show the `alertDialog` on the onPostExecute method I used the following code:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder goLogin = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            goLogin.setMessage("test");
            goLogin.setCancelable(false);
            goLogin.setPositiveButton("ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alertLogin = goLogin.create();
        alertLogin.show();
```

But what I get is the following error:

```
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:148)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:99)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:154)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:379)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at test.test.showAlert(test.java:671)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at test.test.checkResult(test.java:656)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at test.test$login.onPostExecute(test.java:585)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at test.test$login.onPostExecute(test.java:1)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
07-10 14:42:09.710: E/AndroidRuntime(12963):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to pass the context in a different way?

EDIT:
Whole AsyncTask code:

```
private class login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Showing progress dialog

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", "test"));
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlTest, ServiceHandler.POST, params);


    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            error = obj.getBoolean("Error");
            if(!error)
            {
                loginResult = true;
                JSONObject array = obj.getJSONObject("Response");
                name = array.getString("Name");
            }
            else
            {
                loginResult = false;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    //checkResult();
    AlertDialog.Builder reorder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    reorder.setMessage("error");
    reorder.setCancelable(true);
    reorder.setPositiveButton("ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog orderError = reorder.create();
    orderError.show();
}

}
```

Comment: just use currentactivity.this

Comment: @Shadow I've already tried, I get the same error

Comment: in onCreate Activity.this and this are referring to same instance.

Comment: @Alexander `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: your edited code looks different.  AlertDialog alertLogin = goLogin.create();?  where you initialised?

Comment: Where you have defined `mContext = this` in your code???

Comment: @Signo Paste more logcat, and more code. Where you have defined `mContext`?

Comment: @Signo, post your full code, and also have you tried with getApplicationContext()?

Comment: @SumighoshCharuvil yes I've already tried with getApplicationContext() but I had the same error

Comment: @krystian71115 I defined mContext where I define every class variable, and I initialized it inside the OnCreate method

Comment: @Shadow That code is used in order to create the dialog and show it, I initialize AlertLogin with the .create() method

Comment: I think activity do not exist when onPostExecute is executed. That's why mContext become "null". Rest your code is ok and it is working.

Comment: @AnandSingh I never leave the activity, even if I pass this.Activity I get the same error

Comment: @Signo maybe you can create the `AlertDialog` in `onCreate` and use show in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I've posted the full error above

Comment: It seems the base context is null.

Comment: Where are you creating (not execute) AsyncTask?

Comment: @krystian71115 the AsyncTask is inside my class

Comment: Yes but in which method? In onCreate?

Comment: @krystian71115 I call it like this: new login().execute(); Inside the OnPostExecute of another asyncTask

Answer (score 6):

Create constructor of your AsyncTask and do something like this:

```
private class DemoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
         Context context;

    public DemoTask(Context mContext) {
        this.context = mContext;
    }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            AlertDialog.Builder goLogin = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            goLogin.setMessage("test");
            goLogin.setCancelable(false);
            goLogin.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertLogin = goLogin.create();
            alertLogin.show();
        }

    }
```

Here `mContext` is inside `onCreate` Method:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private Context mContext;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = this;

        new DemoTask(mContext).execute();
    }
```

Comment: @Signo please share code of whole activity with `AsyncTask`. It will help me to get more info about your problem.

Comment: I edited my question with the whole AsyncTask code, I used the debug tool and the exception is raised when I initialize the AlertDialog.Builder so the problem is for sure the context passed to it

Comment: @Anand What is mContext in above Ans please update your answer

Comment: @AnandSingh what is use of context if async task is in activity class. I mean why you are making local variable of context inside Async Task even mContext is there in scope.

Comment: @Signo do you initialize `mContext = this;` inside onCreate like I did? If possible please share code of activity till you called your Async task.

Comment: @ajit i have updated my answer, if he is using Async outside of Activity class.

Comment: yes I initialize mContext inside the onCreate method. Sorry but I can't post the whole code

Comment: @Signo there is no problem in your `dialog` code. I myself tested it. Please give a try to my edited answer. Rest without seeing activity class code, it seems difficult to find error.

Answer (score 1):

onPostExecute() is called on main thread. mContext has Activity's context.

Regardless of the fact Activity is destroyed or not, onPostExecute() will be called. When Activity is destroyed, the NPE error will occur while creating Alert Dialog Box. Make sure that Activity is on foreground.

**update:**

code:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(getActivity() == null)
            {
              return; //since activity is in background!
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder goLogin = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            goLogin.setMessage("test");
            goLogin.setCancelable(false);
            goLogin.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertLogin = goLogin.create();
            alertLogin.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you get your servis callback in onPostExecute of your AsyncTask, user can send your app to background and your activity can be destroyed. In this case your context will be null and cannot show an alert dialog.

I think it's not a good solution to show an alert dialog on AsyncTask results. You can show a Toast message. Dialogs use activity context and you can get this error.

Also can get BadTokenException in this kind of usage. To avoid these kind of errors check if your activity null and show dialog in a try catch blog.

Answer (score 0):

Remove last two line of code and add the below line :

Instead of this line

```
AlertDialog alertLogin = goLogin.create();
alertLogin.show();
```

Use this line:

```
goLogin.show();
```